# How is Kate Marsh alive in "Episode 4" of Life is Strange?

Tags: life-is-strange

First of all I have been playing the Episodes in sequence starting from Episode 1.

In Episode 2,

> I clearly saw Kate jumped off the roof and died.

When I started Episode 4 today, I found that Kate is still alive and also

> David Madsen was kicked out of the house in Episode 3 but he is still there in his garage in Episode 4 and thanked me for taking his side when I actually didn't.

Are these things still supposed to happen in Episode 4 regardless of the choices you made in previous Episodes?

Comment: Are you sure and certain someone else isn't playing on your account / computer ? Because yes these events are linked and shouldn't mess up like so.

Comment: Yes, very sure. It's my own computer. I downloaded Episode 4 just today and started playing it after finishing the Episode 3 just yesterday. I also checked the choices I made in Episode 2 from save game and it says "You didn't save Kate".

Comment: Okay, not sure about this one thing. Does playing the game from Episode 1 in a different "save slot" and loading the game from where you left e.g. Episode 4 from _another_ "save slot" affect the overall progress?

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to say here... Saves slots shouldn't interact with one an another.

Comment: If you fast fowarded the game from a save slot that didn't have that sort of progress (If it's even possible), the progress wil just be either "randomized" or set to the default values that the devs intended.

Comment: @Karlyr what the OP is saying in their comments is that you can do the episodes out of order. It sounds like they are saying that they started Episode 1 in one save slot and finished up to Episode 3. Then, they started Episode 4 in a different save slot. I'm going to say that this will in fact ignore either all or some of the decisions you've made, but I can't say for sure. I haven't been able to find any solid evidence to back the claim.

Comment: @TimmyJim I'm doubting that you can even do that, that's why I have problems understanding what the OP did. (And maybe why you aren't finding evidence) From what I recall of the TellTales (I know not the same company), the chapters were locked if not done on that save slot. And I played LiS with 2 save slots with my game too while it was still releasing periodically (my friend was doing a chapter when she came over and I was a few chapters ahead at some point)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What happened as is stated in the comments above is that you started a new game in a different save slot, the game started at episode 4 because you chose to do episode 4.

The choices you make are for 1 save slot (or game).

For example:

- Save Slot A: episode 1 through 3 (your choices, kate died)
- Save Slot B: started at episode 4 (the game makes the choices for you, kate lived)

If you play this game, use the same save slot for every episode